# Is it possible to get database contents from any website without having DB access?

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve the database contents from a website and use it in another website. Is it possible to access the database contents using any scripts ? There are totally 500 + products in the website and they are going to remove those contents now. So before they remove them i want to download all the data and host it in my website. It is not possible to visit each and every page and write down the products information. It will be helpful if I get any kind of script to access the database and download all of them in a specified format.

For eg: We have leech software for forums to get content from another forums.

Comment: You're kidding me right?

Comment: @Jacob Relkin: :) not exactly.. actually i am not doing anything wrong here... i got account in that website and now they are going to remove those contents which is much needed for me.. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: this is something you need to take up with the website owners. If the information is truly yours, they could be in a lot of trouble in removing it. However, if they're removing it due to bill non-payment or something like that and your contract with them doesn't hold any joy, then you're probably fresh outta luck. This is a legal problem, not a programming one (and, as such, depends on the local laws in effect).

Comment: If you are administrator of the website you can easily download all MySQL database in your local hard disk and can restore it in your new website.
Download tool from MySQL dev website "MySQL Administrator", Login into by using your mysql user account and create a backup of your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have any permission to that sites or you are administrator of that site, may be you can SQLdumb or any package for dumping data. But if have not a permission you cant do that.

Comment: im not the admin of that site and i dont have DB access. All i have is an account with them where i can view the data. Now i want that data to come into my website..

Comment: This called "theft" and is illegal.

Comment: owh..you cant do that..you must be the owner of that site if you want to do that. or you can talk to the owner of that sites, of course if they want to share.

Comment: if you want that data. may be you can copy then make your own DB.then input that data manually.

Comment: Pencil and paper :-) (Just kidding)

Comment: haha..its not like that..of course using keyboard it will be better than he steal the data as hacker ;)

Answer (score 3):

No!!!!The question is not whether it is possible or not. It is whether you are allowed to copy from the site or not.

You cannot connect to the databse without the details.

Why don't you contact the website owners to send you the data they are going to remove it anyway?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. I would recommend trying to get in contact with the site owner and explain why you want their database and such and they may let you have it. Otherwise your best bet is to crawl the site and get a copy of every page and then manually populate(or attempt to automate it somehow) your own database from it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you don't have administrative privileges to their site, in which case you can't just issue queries to their database. Their web page acts as a front-end to the database (and their business logic) thus preventing users from ever interacting directly with the data. That set-up is intentional.

The leech software you mention is generally implemented as a scraper of sorts. It downloads the contents of a forum as just a webpage, no different from how a search engine would crawl the Internet. If need be, the leech might store/mimic a cookie in case the forum requires a logged-in user. But in no case does the leech access the site's underlying database.

So your choices are to either write your own crawler, or email the site's administrator (as others have suggested). I'm not going to get into the issues of whether what you're asking for can be considered fair use; you should any legal ramifications before you attempt scraping.